# Data Structure for representing patterns in strings

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, trie

I'm looking for a good data structure to represent strings of the form:

```
Domain:Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2...
```

- Each "Domain" can contain the following pattern characters - `*`, `?` (`*` - 0 or more characters, `?` - 0 or 1 character)
- Each "Key" can contain the following pattern characters - `*`, `?` (`*` - 0 or more characters, `?` - 0 or 1 character)
- Each "Value" can contain the following pattern characters - `*`, `?` (`*` - 0 or more characters, `?` - 0 or 1 character)

Examples:

```
JBoss:*
*:*
JBoss:type=ThreadPool,*
JBoss:type=Thread*,*
JB*:name=http1,type=ConnectionPool
```

If you are familiar with JMX ObjectName's then essentially this is the ObjectName pattern.

I'm looking for ways to easily store a rule corresponding to each pattern and be able to quickly delete,update and add new rules.

I started out by using a Prefix Trie, but got stuck with the pattern characters `*`, `?`.

Comment: How do you resolve conflicts on matching rules, is it like a longest prefix match? For instance, if you had the two rules, JBoss:* and * : *,  JBoss:key=value would match both. Do you pick the longest match?

Comment: Hi Kyun,  You are right I would pick the longest match.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to build an [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite-state_machine) like trie, one which allows transitions to multiple states. This, of course, adds the complexity of having another data structure which maps to multiple states given a set of characters to match. For instance, with your example:

```
JBoss:*
*:*
JBoss:type=ThreadPool,*
JBoss:type=Thread*,*
JB*:name=http1,type=ConnectionPool
```

Lets say you try to match `JBoxx:name=*`

When you match the substring `JBo`, you would need a data structure to hold the states `JBo` and `JB*` and `*` since you have three branches at this point. When the `x` comes in, you can discard the `JBo` route since its a dead end and use `JB*` and `*`. The easy implementation is to have a set of possible match states at any given time and try the next character on each of them. You would also need a way to resolve multiple matches (as in this case) - perhaps something as simple as a longest match?

It all seems to make sense when you think of the trie as an NFA instead of the well-accepted DFA format.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Kyun,Thanks for the suggestions. I believe a similar problem exists in Topic routing in messaging frameworks where messages have to be routed based on similar patterns. Here is a link : http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/tag/dfa/

Comment: Looks very similar! I was about to suggest converting your rules to a DFA once you have the NFA but that'll likely make your rule updates slower?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use a [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this other thread: [Efficient data structure for word lookup with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815083/efficient-data-structure-for-word-lookup-with-wildcards)

Or this site: [Wildcard queries](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/wildcard-queries-1.html)

The second site ends with "We can thus handle wildcard queries that contain a single * symbol using two B-trees, the normal B-tree and a reverse B-tree.".

This may be over the top for you, but it may be worth the read.

Good luck

Comment: You could also use some other library, such as Lucene to store and index the values..