# Efficient data structure to hold strings with wildcards

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

This question is almost the opposite of [Efficient data structure for word lookup with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815083/efficient-data-structure-for-word-lookup-with-wildcards)

Suppose we have a database of `urls`

```
http://aaa.com/
http://bbb.com/
http://ccc.com/
....
```

To find if a `url` is on the list I can make a `binary-search` and get the results in `O(log n)` time, n the size of the list.

This structure served well for many years but now I'd like to have wildcards in the database entries, like:

```
http://*aaa.com/*
http://*bbb.com/*
http://*ccc.com/
....
```

And the naive search would result in a full scan with `O(n)` time for finding.

Which data structure could have find in less than `O(n)`?

Comment: you could still do binary search, but maintain the sorted lists of know urls with strings starting from behind

Comment: the query url: `http://test.ccc.com/` result `true`

Comment: is http ://sasccc.com a valid query ie without a dot separator ?

Comment: could you split the urls into a fixed number of fields, where a field could be wild or specified? or do you need wild cards to be able to appear anywhere in the url (e.g `http*://*ca*.c/*/*.html`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient data structure for word lookup with wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815083/efficient-data-structure-for-word-lookup-with-wildcards)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: @ppaulojr: So it is - my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the all the urls are known beforehand, then you could just build a finite automaton, which will solve your problem with queries in O(url length).

This finite automaton can be built as a regexp:

```
http://(.*aaa\.com/.*|.*bbb\.com/.*|.*ccc\.com/)$
```

Here's some python code. After re.compile(), each query is very fast.

```
import re

urls = re.compile("http://(.*aaa\.com/.*|.*bbb\.com/.*|.*ccc\.com/)$")

print urls.match("http://testaaa.com/") is not None
> True
print urls.match("http://somethingbbb.com/dir") is not None
> True
print urls.match("http://ccc.com/") is not None
> True
print urls.match("http://testccc.com/") is not None
> True
print urls.match("http://testccc.com/ddd") is not None
> False
print urls.match("http://ddd.com/") is not None
> False
```

Comment: I guess you cannot `re.compile` a very large string :)

Comment: If the regexp implementation is not up to the task, you can always build the automaton yourself. This will provide you better control over how much memory is used.